# ASP.NET MVC. Routing manager. Resolve routes issues with similar link values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I need advice about a problem with which I recently encountered. The essence of the problem: in my web site I have a `Controller`. Let it be `ProductController`. And, of course, I have some `Actions` in it:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{ 
 public virtual ActionResult ProductDetails(string slug)
    public virtual ActionResult ProductList (string slug, string category, string filter)
}
```

`Filter` parameter can be empty. My routes in `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapRoute("ProudctsList", "products/{slug}/{category}/{selectedFilters}", MVC.Product.ProductList()
                .AddRouteValue("selectedFilters", ""));
routes.MapRoute("Products", "products/{slug}", MVC.Product.ProductDetails());
routes.MapRoute("CustomPage", "custom/{slug}", MVC.CustomPage.Index());
......
routes.MapRoute("BrandCollectionDetails", "brand/{slug}/{collectionId}", MVC.Brand.BrandCollectionDetails());    
routes.MapRoute("BrandDetails", "brand/{slug}", MVC.Brand.BrandDetails());
routes.MapRoute("HomePage", "", MVC.Home.Index());                   
routes.MapRoute("Sales.Index", "sales", MVC.Sales.Index());
```

According to requirements I need to remove `products` from the `Url`. I mean that if `Url` has such scheme product/cars/audi/black - it should be just cars/audio/black. And also I need to remove `custom` from the `Url`. As you could see, I'll get `Urls` with the same scheme. I need to say that I have I `List` of custom `Urls`:

```
List<string> customPages = new List<string> {/Ferrari, ...}
```

I mean that all `Urls` with such scheme: `/{something}` should be checked using this `List`.
I just need to remove `products/` segment from this `Urls` `products/{slug}/{category}/{filter}` and `custom` from this `custom/{slug}` and direct user to the necessary `Controller Action`. I have no ideas how to build custom route manager that should resolve this issues and need experts help. Please, tell me if the issue is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem. It looks like your specific problem can be solved by creating an implementation of the IRouteConstraint.

This will allow you to dynamically override the default routing functionality of your application.

```
public class ProductUrlConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        List<string> customPages = new List<string> {"Ferrari", "Porche"};

        if (values[parameterName] != null)
        {
            var slug= values[parameterName].ToString();
            var product = customPages.Where(p => p == slug).FirstOrDefault();
            if(!string.isNullorEmpty(product))
            {
                 HttpContext.Items["customProduct"] = product;
                 return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use your implementation of the IRouteConstraint in your route definition as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductRoute",
    url: "{*customProduct}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Product", action = "Index"},
    constraints: new { customProduct= new ProductUrlConstraint() }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The action would then follow like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string permalink)
{
    var page = HttpContext.Items["customProduct"].ToString();
    //dont forget to check for null :)
    //model/ view logic
}
```

You might have to do some custom string processing within your action depending on your later requirements.

Storing the custom product in the HttpContext is simply a performance consideration.